# eval-defun ignores lexical-binding

Tags: lexical-scoping

Today I discovered that if you re-evaluate a defun using `eval-defun` (<kbd>C-M-x</kbd>) in a buffer with `lexical-binding` set to `t`, the defun is recreated as an ordinary lambda, not a closure.

For example, after you evaluate this file:

```
;;; -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-

(defun foo (x) (lambda (y) (+ x y)))
```

Then `(symbol-function 'foo)` returns

```
(closure (t) (x) (function (lambda (y) (+ x y))))
```

But if you put point in the body of the function, press <kbd>C-M-x</kbd>, and evaluate `(symbol-function 'foo)` again, you get:

```
(lambda (x) (function (lambda (y) (+ x y))))
```

Certainly not the same thing, and in fact it throws a `void-variable` error when you call the returned function, if `x` is not globally bound.

Is this the intended behavior?  Do I just need to remember not to use `eval-defun` but rather `eval-buffer` whenever I modify a function in a file where `lexical-binding` is `t`?

I'm using Emacs 25.0.50.2.

Comment: *Do I just need to remember not to use eval-defun but rather eval-buffer whenever I modify a function in a file where lexical-binding is t?* Yes, it seems so.

Comment: @Sean: This would be a bug.  I can't reproduce it here, tho.  Did you add the `-*- lexical-binding: t; -*-` cookie after you opened the file, by any chance?

Comment: @Stefan: Yes I did, and that indeed makes the difference.  If you put your response in an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-*- lexical-binding: t; -*-` only takes effect when you open the file.  So after adding it, you need to re-open the file otherwise your buffer is still in dynamic-binding mode.

Comment: This is a gotcha, which should be pointed out in the doc.

Comment: It applies to all file-local variables.  So if it needs to be documented it's in the section about file-local variables, rather than the section about lexical-binding or about eval-defun.